# Dynamic class with conditionals using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am iterating over a list of items, and making a checkbox input.  I want to have a class for when it is checked, and another(or absence of) if it is unchecked.

Currently there is an array on the $scope that keeps track if the item is checked or not, so I was trying to put that conditional in t the `ng-scope`, but the syntax seems to be a problem:

In this example, the css class `.test` would be present if the uniqJoke exists, which of course it always does because we are iterating over them:

```
  <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="uniqJoke in uniqJokeTypes">
    Each Joke Type
    <div class="type-filter-button type-filter-button-{{uniqJoke}}" ng-class="{test: uniqJoke}" ng-click="jokeTypeClick(uniqJoke)">
      <label ng-bind="uniqJoke"></label>
      <!-- <input type="checkbox" ng-model="JokeTypeFilter[uniqJoke]" hidden/> -->
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="uniqJoke" hidden/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Let's say there are some types {`funny`, `pirate`, `knock-knock`, ...}. But how would I add the css class dynamically based on if the joke exists in the associative array variable `JokeTypeFilter{ funny:true, pirate:true, knock-knock:false }`

The following does not work (syntax error):

> ng-class="{ {{uniqJoke}}: JokeTypeFilter[uniqJoke] }"

and this ownt work because it would insert the class `uniqJoke` if the condition matched:

> ng-class="{ uniqJoke: JokeTypeFilter[uniqJoke] }"

but I would like the div to have `.pirate` if `JokeTypeFilter[pirate] == true`.

Answer (score 3):

One option is using an expression in the `class` attribute itself. Something like this:

```
 class="type-filter-button type-filter-button-{{uniqJoke}} {{JokeTypeFilter[uniqJoke]?uniqJoke:''}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-class` attribute can take a controller function call, so you can just do the following in HTML attribute:

```
ng-class="jokeCssClasses()"
```

Then, in your controller, define the function call that return a map of joke names and values:

```
$scope.jokeCssClasses = function() {
    return { funny:true, pirate:true, knock-knock:false };
};
```

From the function, you can construct a map from the list of joke types using `angular.forEach`, or any iteration mechanism to your liking.

---

**UPDATE**: Here's to show what I meant by 'constructing a map' from `angular.forEach`. Suppose `$scope.uniqJokeTypes` is an array, you can do the following:

```
$scope.jokeCssClasses = function() {
    var map = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.uniqJokeTypes, function(joke) {
        map[joke] = true;
    });
    return map;
}
```

You can read more on how to do iteration here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: you are returning literals.   The items are dynamic, so I don't know the names.  how to do it dynamically, as `$scope.jokeCssClasses = function(uniqType) {return { uniqType:true };}` should return the string literal `uniqType` as a class

Comment: @chrisFrisina That's exactly the reason why I pointed out about `angular.forEach`. You can use it to construct a map dynamically. I just added a concrete example to you now. If you debug your browser, you'll see that on each iteration, the variable `joke` will be each joke type in the list.